# HTML/CSS Tabstrip

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm looking to write / emulate a tab strip using HTML & CSS only.

I will progressively enhance this with JavaScript and do not need any help with that.

I've taken ideas from [this page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/#) Example 6

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc2WD/)

---

Please feel free to be pedantic about my current HTML and CSS markup. I'm looking to write this from scratch properly using HTML5 and CSS3 standards and am hoping to avoid my usual "If it works the quality of the markup doesn't matter. jQuery will come along and fix it for me!" attitude.

---

Here is my HTML currently have a markup of :

```
<div class="tabs">
    <section>
        <a> link 1 </a>
        <div> Content 1 </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a> link 2 </a>
        <div> Content 2 </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

---

Here is the (stripped) CSS :

```
.tabs {
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs > section > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.tabs > section {
    display: inline;
}

.tabs > section:not(:target) > div {   
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

There are 3 css issues that I am troubled with.

1. The `div.tabs` only has floated and absolute children so does not have any "real content" and there is no border around it. How do I get it to have a proper border?
2. the `.tabs > section > div` has a width of 100% but does not match the 100% width of the parent `div.tabs` due to the extra padding. My understanding of the box model is lacking here. How do I set it to have a width matching the `div.tabs` parent?
3. How do I make the content `.tabs > section > div` Sit just underneath the `<a>` of the tab strip without setting the css `top` value to a finicky `"43px"`. What's the proper way to do generic positioning in these situations?

**Disclaimer** I don't care about proper browser support. Feel free to use HTML5 / CSS3. I'll use JavaScript to enhance the IE8 functionality properly.

---

If it helps this is the full CSS

```
.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
}

.tabs > section > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.tabs > section {
    display: inline;
}

.tabs > section > div {
    z-index: -2;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.tabs > section:not(:target) > div {   
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: pedantic comment on the HTML: it looks like you are combining navigation (tabs) with content (sections). Those likely need to be separate things.

Comment: @DA navigation is page by page navigation. I want to show you content on a single page in a tabbed manner. I will have a seperate piece of navigation on the page aswell for website navigation. I'm not sure whether the navigation belongs inside the sections or not

Comment: @Raynos...the specification states "The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page" so it can be used for either. SHOULD it be? Well, like with most HTML, a lot of it is open to personal interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a working version of your tabs. Here is a [jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/XxpKZ/17/). (However, I wasn't able to solve all your dilemmas. Read below.)

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }

.tabs > section > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    }

.tabs > section > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -50000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }

.tabs > section:target > div {
    left: 0;
    }

.tabs > section:not(:target)#one > div {
    left: 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <section id="one">
        <a href="#one">link 1</a>
        <div> Content 1 </div>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <a href="#two">link 2</a>
        <div> Content 2 </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Addressing the three questions:

1. The tab div does collapse because of floating and absolutely-positioned objects. The only options I see are to set height or overflow:hidden with bottom padding.
2. I was able to get the width set to that of div.tabs in my CSS above. That's probably a function of `position: relative`.
3. Again since all the objects are taken out of flow, I don't see a way without JavaScript to make the `section > div`s aware of the anchor height.

PS. I liked the use of :target and was able to get your content block to switch as well as have a default.

Comment: I can get it to work nicely with `:target` myself. I prefer their use of `z-index` rather then your use of `left` to set the active content. My problem with "#2" was using `padding` and `width: 100%` together as adding padding is not included in the width in the box model.

Comment: For some reason my earlier iteration had trouble with z-index but it appears that that will work too. (I changed it here - http://jsfiddle.net/XxpKZ/19/) You could use a % padding (ex. padding: 10px 10%;) and a width of 100% - 2*padding%.

Comment: I like the % padding ! awesome. Now how do I trick the `div.tabs` into having some kind of relative invisible content so I can give it a border

Comment: Outside of javascript, you can only do a set height for div.tabs. At least as far as I know (use either method I mentioned above). With javascript I can think of a couple of options.

Answer (score 0):

All of your questions can be answered if you separate the tabs and content into two different containers like the example you posted did. Just clear the floats after the tabs.

```
<div class="tabbed-area">

    <ul class="tabs group">
        <li><a href="#box-one">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#box-two">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#box-three">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="box-wrap">

        <div id="box-one">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="box-two">
            <p>Feugiat...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box-three">
            <p>Pellen...</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that makes the functionality based on the `:target` selector a mess. This isn't actaully a viable option in terms of pinpointing the attached `<li>` to the `div:target`. If you take a look at example 6 on the inspiration website you'll see how I intend to make the `<a>` stand out based on the current `:target` tab. Not to mention that the semantic markup of the <section> make more sense with the tab link and tab content grouped together.

Comment: Most tab solutions do use this separation, but I do agree that it lacks semantic value.

Comment: @LeRoy I know how such a solution works, but I'm trying to layer this website properly so the HTML markup can stand on its own without merely being a tool used by the javascript. I want people to be able to view the source without disgust.

Comment: @Raynos I agree with your stance.